# Show list of references in ascending order of First name in natbib of Latex

Tags: bibliographies

I am struggling to get my thesis list of references in ascending order of First name. By following code I am getting references in order of Last name.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1} % Introduction
\chapter{Flow over permeable sheet} 
The flow due to stretching of a flat surface was first investigated by Aziz \cite{Aziz}. 
Brady and Aroesty \cite{Aroesty} analyzed the flow inside a stretching channel or tube and the flow outside the stretching tube was examined by Hassanien \cite{Hassanien}.
\input{Chapters/Chapter3} % Second Paper
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

with the bib file:

```
@article{Aroesty, 
  author = "J. Aroesty and J. F. Gross",
  title = "flow in small blood vessels",
  volume = "9",
  year='2000'} 
@article{AzizA,
  author = "Aziz Aboud, 
  title=Homotopy analysis method",
  volume = "3",
  year="2008"}
```

Getting output as

```
[1] Hassanien I A, "Micropolar Boundary-Layer Flow", vol 21, 2012
 [2] Aziz Aboud, "Homotopy analysis method", vol 3, 2008
 [3] M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, "characteristics of a continuous stretching surface", vol 45, pp. 215-218,1995
 [4] J. Aroesty and J. F. Gross, "flow in small blood vessels", vol 1, 2000
```

I want these references to be ordered by the first names, as follows:

```
[1] Aziz Aboud, "Homotopy analysis method", vol 3, 2008
[2] Hassanien I A, "Micropolar Boundary-Layer Flow", vol 21, 2012
[3] J. Aroesty and J. F. Gross, "flow in small blood vessels", vol 1, 2000
[4] M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, "characteristics of a continuous stretching surface", vol 45, pp. 215-218,1995
```